# what is causing Unhandled exception at memory : Stack overflow

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I'm new to C++ and I'm implementing the Canny edge detector algorithm by myself. for that, I've declared some 2D arrays. it gives me the error " Unhandled exception at 0x000A1809 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00E92000)"

I minimized the number of elements of my arrays, and it worked. but when I need arrays with more elements

```
//2.Gradian Calculation: a.Calculating Gx and Gy   b.Calculation sqrt(Gx^2 + Gy^2)   c.Calculating the gradiant orientation
int Fx[3][3] = { {-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,1} };
int Fy[3][3] = { {1,2,1},{0,0,0},{-1,-2,-1} };
int image[100][100] = { 50 };
int gradian_x[100][100] = { 0 };
int gradian_y[100][100] = { 0 };
double edgeStrength[100][100] = { 0 };

//Calculating Gx
for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 99; j++)
    {
        gradian_x[j][i] = image[j - 1][i - 1] * Fx[0][0] + image[j][i - 1] * Fx[1][0] + image[j + 1][i - 1] * Fx[2][0] + image[j + 1][i + 1] * Fx[2][2] + image[j][i + 1] * Fx[1][2] + image[j - 1][i + 1] * Fx[0][2];

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], or at least the complete function. The problem is most likely because there is not enough space on the stack for such huge local variables.

Comment: If _it worked_ for smaller arrays, then your larger arrays likely do not fit in the process stack space. Either increase the stack size limit, or, better, allocate arrays dynamically (i.e., use vectors).

Comment: @Jabberwocky , You mean I don't have enough space on my whole computer for just four 2d arrays?

Comment: Mr. Daniel Langr, how should I increase my stack space?
and why is it better to use vectors?

Comment: @M.H.Muhamadi Stack space != program available space != computer available memory. These three things are distinct and there is no mapping between them (other than size relations: stack space < program available space < computer available memory).

Comment: @M.H.Muhamadi You may have as much space on your hard drive or in RAM as you want. This does not change the stack size limit for processes.

Comment: @M.H.Muhamadi That depend on your operating system. However, I would recommend to use dynamic arrays (vectors) instead. It's better simply because it stores array elements on heap (instead of stack).

Comment: @M.H.Muhamadi It depends. A much better way (IMO) would be to use some library that do the work for you. Such as Eigen.

Comment: Fix with Project > Properties > Linker > System, "Stack Reserve Size" setting.  Or allocate the arrays with new[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack space is limited. Provided that `int` is 4 bytes on your platform and `double` is 8 bytes, you ask for 195 kiB memory, which may or may not be available in stack (that's ignoring any other necessary things from stack like function calls etc).

For storing larger sets of data, you should use dynamic memory allocation with `std::vector` (it uses heap memory instead of stack memory, which is much larger than stack):

```
const int initialValue = 50;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> image (100, std::vector<int>(100, initial_value);
```

Note that `int image[100][100] = { 50 };` will initialize **only** `image[0][0]` to 50 and the rest of the e lements to 0. It is fixed in above example (all elements are initialized with 50 there), but if you want to retain that behaviour, you should make `initial_value` to be equal to 0 and change `image[0][0]` directly.

---

For increased performance, you should preferable use a specialized library like `Eigen`. If you don't want external resources, you may want to use `std::vector<std::array<int, 100>>` instead, which will allocate memory in single block (better for processor cache):

```
std::array<int, 100> initialArray;
std::fill(initialArray.begin(), initialArray.end(), 50);
std::vector<std::array<int, 100>> image (100, initialArray);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a _vector-of-vectors_ if I cared about performance. This approach does not store all the elements contiguously in memory. I would either use a 1D vectors (optionally wrapped with some 2D accessor functions), or use some existing library (such as Eigen).

Comment: @DanielLangr AFAIK, `std::vector<std::array>` should be allocated in one block as well, so I suggested Eigen + vector of arrays. IMO, it's simpler than rolling a wrapper for 2D access.